# getUserMedia in Opera 26 (chromium) from localhost blocked

Tags: javascript, localhost, opera, webrtc, getusermedia

I have a `test.html` which is served through apache.

Calls to `getUserMedia` (to access the webcam) from http://localhost/test.html **are blocked by Opera (26).** Opera doesn't allow me to change that in the preferences.

Is there any way how to allow `getUserMedia` from localhost in Opera?

Answer (score 0):

> Opera 26 automatically blocks it and doesn't allow me to change it in preferences

How does that blocking look like?

I have a `index.html` and `main.js` ([thanks to simpl.info](http://simpl.info/getusermedia/)) in `getusermedia/` and serve them with:

```
$ cd getusermedia/
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

And everything works as expected.

[image]

I'm on a mac with Opera 27.

Comment: I use Win 8 and my Opera automaticaly adds localhost into an exception list in multimedia settings. I see the localhost item in the list but it is not editable. I can't allow audio and video for this localhost (or 127.0.0.1) item. However other items are changeable, I can use getUserMedia on another domains. It might also be an issue of my antivirus (Avast) or firewall. As a localserver I use Apache 2.4.